# Make variable point to another variable

Tags: c#, pointers, unity-game-engine

I need to have an instance which is the pointer of another instance. Basically, I will have two instances called **A** and **B** created from the same class. whenever I will change an attribute of A instance the B instances attribute will be changed. Basically, the attributes will have the same address on the memory.

*I just want to reach the same object with different variable names. Whenever one of them will be edited, the other one should be edited too.*

> How can I do that in Unity with c#?

Comment: You should avoid thinking about pointers in C#

Comment: "I will change an attiribute of A instance the B instances attiribute will be changed." - Doesn't that mean you only have one instance, but two variables (A and B) referencing the same instance? This is how C# already behaves for reference types. I'm not sure what you're asking. Can you clarify?

Comment: For example: `var a = new MyClass(); var b = a; a.Name = "John"; Console.WriteLine(b.Name);` would print "John", because the variables `a` and `b` both point to the same instance of `MyClass`.

Comment: I will have 2 instances with same type. Whenever one of them will be edited, the other one should be edited too. It's more like aliasing.

Comment: Do you mean that you only want some of the properties to be common (in terms of memory)? Is there a benefit over using two references to the same instance?

Comment: I just want to reach the same object with different variable names. I guess your example can fix my issue. I am trying it right now and let you know if it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I will have 2 instances with same type. Whenever one of them will be
>   edited, the other one should be edited too.
>
> I just want to reach the same object with different variable names.

You can use properties to fake pointing to another variable. This is easily done with the `get` and `set` accessors.

Let's say that the main variable is named score:

```
public int score;
```

You can point to the score variable with two other variables:

```
public int scoreWithDifferentName1
{
    get { return score; }
    set { score = value; }
}
```

and

```
public int scoreWithDifferentName2
{
    get { return score; }
    set { score = value; }
}
```

Now, you can change the score variable or access it with those two property variables above:

```
scoreWithDifferentName1 = 0;
Debug.Log(scoreWithDifferentName1);
```

Or

```
scoreWithDifferentName2 = 3;
Debug.Log(scoreWithDifferentName2);
```

---

Another option is to use `IntPtr` but this is not necessary. The C# property feature is enough to give you what want. This works both for value and reference types.

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a design question of how you want your classes to look like and what are their responsibilities. I'm not sure what is the purpose of the class that you're talking about but the obvious solution here is an attribute with a [static](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static#example-1) modifier.
Adding a static attribute to your class will insure it will have the same value across all instances, i.e.:

```
public class ClassX
{
    public static string staticVar = "This is a static string";
    private string var1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're describing the regular way reference types work in C#:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
}

void Test()
{
    var a = new MyClass();
    a.Name = "Test";
    var b = a;

    Console.WriteLine(a.Name); // "Test"
    Console.WriteLine(b.Name); // "Test"

    b.Name = "MossTeMuerA";
    Console.WriteLine(a.Name); // "MossTeMuerA"
    Console.WriteLine(b.Name); // "MossTeMuerA"

    Mutate(a);
    Console.WriteLine(a.Name); // "John"
    Console.WriteLine(b.Name); // "John"
}

void Mutate(MyClass myClass)
{
    myClass.Name = "John";
}
```

[Example 1](https://rextester.com/TPUS36761)

Note that if you want to modify which class instance the variable passed to a method points to, you need to use the `ref` keyword:

```
void Test()
{
    var a = new MyClass();
    a.Name = "Test";
    var b = a;

    Console.WriteLine(a.Name); // "Test"
    Console.WriteLine(b.Name); // "Test"

    Mutate(ref a);
    Console.WriteLine(a.Name); // "John"
    Console.WriteLine(b.Name); // "Test"
}

void Mutate(ref MyClass myClass)
{
    myClass = new MyClass();
    myClass.Name = "John";
}
```

[Example 2](https://rextester.com/IPJ3614)

There is also another keyword, `out`, which allows a method to instantiate an object in the scope of the caller by passing in the variable you want to populate:

```
void Test()
{
    MyClass a;
    Instantiate(out a);
    Console.WriteLine(a.Name); // "John"
}

void Instantiate(out MyClass myClass)
{
    myClass = new MyClass();
    myClass.Name = "John";
}
```

[Example 3](https://rextester.com/UGTP25336)